# How to Color-Code Worksheet Using For.. Next Loop and Select Case?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and having a hard time debugging the code block below. My goal is to color code some of the rows (say 5% of them) in the active worksheet based on the contents of the cells in column 7. Error Code is Runtime Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: lastRow is working well in other blocks of code, and it is declared and assigned earlier in the program, so I don't currently suspect it of being the problem.

```
' Color code data based on strings or numbers found in column 7
  Dim lastRow as Integer
  lastRow = 9,000
  Dim blockStatus As Variant

  For blockRow = 3 To lastRow
' the following row triggers runtime error    
    blockStatus = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(blockRow, 7)).Value
      Select Case blockStatus
          Case Is = "ADMIN*"
          Range(Cells(blockRow, 1), Cells(blockRow, 11)).Font.Bold = True
          Case Is = "OTHER*"
          Range(Cells(blockRow, 1), Cells(blockRow, 11)).Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
          Case Is = "*@*"
          Range(Cells(blockRow, 1), Cells(blockRow, 11)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
          Case Else
      End Select
  Next blockRow
```

Comment: You must assign a value to ***lastRow***.  That is why the `Cells()` are dying.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the bit of code here to solve that. In the full macro program, lastRow is declared and assigned before the program gets to this block.

Comment: Try changing blockStatus = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(blockRow, 7)).Value to blockStatus = ActiveSheet.Cells(blockRow, 7)

Comment: @Absinthe, with your change I no longer get the runtime error, but the program doesn't color code any of the rows at all. Seems like 'blockStatus' is not getting assigned the value from Cells() and so the 'Case Else' (i.e., do nothing) is invoked.

Comment: Does your `blockStatus` variable actually contain strings such as `"ADMIN*"` or are you thinking that the `*` will act as a wildcard?

Comment: You are inconsistent in your referencing. This is not the source of your problem today but it might be tomorrow.  You write `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range` which explicitly identifies the workbook and worksheet for Range.  But all other Ranges and Cells assume the active workbook and sheet. Assuming the workbook and worksheet will get you into trouble one day.

Comment: @YowE3K... well that's embarrassing. I do have a basic-level background in Java and should have realized that a wildcard wouldn't work, not sure where I got that idea. Thank you very much for taking the time to point that out.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, thanks for the advice - the inconsistency you see came from a long line of tries to debug that code block; I'll be striving for more consistency going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absinthe's comment solves your error (the parameters for a range can be either an address, or **two** cells).

I believe why your code is then not doing what you expect is that you intend your `Case` statement to be performing a `Like` operation on the strings mentioned.

If so, change your code as follows:

```
With ActiveSheet
    For blockRow = 3 To lastRow
        blockStatus = .Cells(blockRow, 7).Value
        With .Range(.Cells(blockRow, 1), .Cells(blockRow, 11))
            Select Case True
                Case blockStatus Like "ADMIN*"
                    .Font.Bold = True
                Case blockStatus Like "OTHER*"
                    .Font.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                Case blockStatus Like "*@*"
                    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                Case Else
            End Select
        End With
    Next blockRow
End With
```

(Note: It's not possible to do a `Case Like "ADMIN*"`, which is why I have used the rather unintuitive `Select Case True` with `Case` statements such as `Case blockStatus Like "ADMIN*"`.)